# Creating a database when using firestore in datastore mode via gcloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud

Is there any way to create a database when using firestore in datastore mode via gcloud(command line) without using the UI https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/quickstart as per the gcloud doc it seems one can only manage indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today (July 2021) you can create databases in either mode with `gcloud firestore databases create` for Firestore in native mode, and `gcloud datastore databases create` for Firestore in Datastore mode.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way with gcloud today (22 Apr 2019) to specify the mode you want for Cloud Firestore.

Comment: Is there a way now? (July 2021)